# How to put joined variable in separate lines

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have GroupSeparatelines  from this code which i want to place in html below in separate lines. How do i implement this?

```
  vm.GroupSeparatelines = vm.Group.map(function (e) {
                            return e.code;
                        }).join("<br>");
```

HTML below

```
<strong>Group(s) : {{vm.GroupSeparatelines }} </strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` to get line brakes from `<br>` tags:

```
<strong [innerHTML]="'Group(s) ' + vm.GroupSeparatelines"></strong>
```

Comment: will this work in old angularJS. Does not seem to work for me

Comment: In that case try to replace `[innerHTML]` with `ng-bind-html`. But not sure about this

Comment: Seems you need to add this module http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js  `var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ["ngSanitize"]);` Without it, AngularJs poops error - *Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.*

Comment: Hey i approached a different way to get what i want. Thanks for help. See my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>Group(s) : <small ng-repeat="x in vm.Group"><br>{{x.code}}</small> </strong>
```

This way works for me